# Duda sobre formato de fecha en php

Tags: php

Quiero imprimir una fecha actual en php, pero no tengo claro cual es el formato que esta tiene, el ejemplo que debo seguir es este: 
"1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z"

Comment: Buenas David. En este enlace http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php tienes la documentación necesaria para mostrar la fecha en el formato deseado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El formato que muestras es `UTC` (Tiempo Universal Coordinado), con un designador `UTC` especial `Z` (Zulu).

Puedes usar la clase [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php):

```
echo ( new DateTime() )->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'); // 2017-08-23T03:25:06Z
```

<kbd>[Ver Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe93523061c21da2c3ccd137dc14804cff3d69f4)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Yo conozco una forma mas sencilla de imprimir la fecha y hora actual:

```
    $Ahora = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    echo $Ahora;
```

Tu decides en que formato la quieres jugando con los parámetros "Y-m-d H:i:s"

Answer (score 0):

El formato que buscas es el **ISO 8601**

Puedes mostrar la fecha actual en dicho formato de la siguiente manera

```
<?php
echo date('c');
```

Resultado:

```
2017-08-23T02:02:30+02:00
```

Puedes encontrar más informacion en [date()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) y en [ISO 8601](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

No sé si sea tarde pero también estoy en el desarrollo de la facturación electrónica y éste me funcionó. Fuente:https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/05/08/obtener-fecha-microsegundos-php/

```
$ahora = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', number_format(microtime(true), 3, '.', ''));
$local = $ahora->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Bogota'));
$formateado = $local->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
$fecha = substr($formateado, 0, -3).'Z';
```